# How can I use user defined function in select statement as cursor to achieve the results?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have below cursors:

```
OPEN p_results FOR
      SELECT distinct S02.CONVERSATION_ID, S02.INTERNAL_USI, S02.PRN,  S02.CRN, 
             S01.EARLIEST_B_DATE "Bank Date", S01.EARLIEST_B_NARRATIVE||'DSEC' "BN", 
             abs(S01.TOTAL_B_AMOUNT - S02.TOTAL_C_AMOUNT) "GA", 
             decode(S01.EXTRA_FLAG_4,1,'OP',2,'UP') "Batch Status", 
             (case 
                when S01.latest_b_date > S02.latest_c_date then S01.latest_b_date 
                else S02.latest_c_date 
              end ) Effective_Date, S02.ICC_ID,  
             S02.MATCH_METHOD,
             S01.TOTAL_B_AMOUNT                     
      FROM TTPAY S01,   
           TTCONT S02    
      Where S01.EXTRA_FLAG_4 in (1,2) 
      and   S02.EXTRA_FLAG_4 in (1,2) 
      and   S01.Match_no = 0 
      and   S02.Match_no = 0 
      and S01.PRN = S02.PRN;
```

For this piece of code, I have to made the changes that if effective date in below result is a holiday or falls in weekend, then I need to add +1 and for Saturday +2 else I will use the result as it is returned in below code as effective_date.

```
(case 
        when S01.latest_b_date > S02.latest_c_date then S01.latest_b_date 
        else S02.latest_c_date 
      end ) Effective_Date
```

I have a function called `WORKING_DAY` which takes one date as parameter and returns boolean value as `TRUE` or `FALSE` after it checks holiday calendar and weekend.

How can I use that function in above code snippet effectively to get the required date?

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Answer (score 0):

> I have a function called `WORKING_DAY` which takes one date as parameter and returns boolean value as `TRUE` or `FALSE` after it checks holiday calendar and weekend.
>
> How can I use that function in above code snippet effectively to get the required date?

You cannot use it in an SQL statement as `BOOLEAN` is a [PL/SQL data type](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/datatypes.htm#LNPLS003) and does not exist in [SQL](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF0021).

If you want to return a truthy value in SQL then return a literal (i.e. `0`/`1` or `'Y'`/`'N'` etc.) and compare that if you need to.

So your function should be changed from returning the `BOOLEAN` (PL/SQL only) data type to:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION is_working_day(
  dt IN DATE
) RETURN NUMBER
IS
  is_working_day BOOLEAN;
BEGIN
  -- do stuff.

  IF is_working_day THEN
    RETURN 1;
  ELSE
    RETURN 0;
  END IF;
END;
/
```

---

**Update**

> after changing the function, how can I use that function in that code snippet to get the require effective date?

You cannot use that function to determine how many days you need to add. The function returns a truthy value so unless you are going to iterate over each successive day and test whether it is a working day (which is hard to do in SQL) then your current method of returning a truthy value will not work.

Instead, move the logic into a function which tells you how many days to add:

```
CREATE FUNCTION days_until_next_working_day(
  dt IN DATE
) RETURN INTEGER
IS
  current_day DATE := dt;
BEGIN
  WHILE NOT is_working_day( current_day ) LOOP
    current_day := current_day + INTERVAL '1' DAY;
  END LOOP;
  RETURN current_day - dt;
END;
/
```

*(There is likely to be a more efficient way to write this to calculate the next working day rather than iterating over each successive day but we don't know how you are determining holidays, etc. so we can't optimise it.)*

Then just add the return value into your SQL query to skip that many days.

Comment: Thanks, but after changing the function, how can I use that function in that code snippet to get the require effective date?

Comment: @BikashKumarBehera I wouldn't as you have no idea how many days you need to add. Instead of returning a truthy value I'd rename the function to `number_of_days_until_next_working_day` and return 0 if it is a working day or else return the number of days until it next is a working day from the function.

Comment: The other way is to rewrite the query to PL/SQL. I think it is better approach - you never know who/what is using is_working_day() function. Just close your query in begin-end;

Comment: Almost there....I have one lookup table HOLIDAY_CALENDAR where list of holiday dates are stored for 2020. So now the question is how exactly the code should be look like after including this function to get the effective date..

Comment: @MT0, I tried to compile the given code for the days_until_next_working_day function it gives exception "[Error] PLS-00306 (7: 9): PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'NOT'" and "[Error] PLS-00382 (10: 10): PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type".

Moreover, I want to return date in days_until_next_working_day function. Can you assist me on same?

Comment: @BikashKumarBehera The top part of the answer tells you what you need to do to call your function in SQL. The bottom part of the answer tells that "your current method of returning a truthy value will not work." and to "move the logic into a function which tells you how many days to add"; this means that you can use function returning a `BOOLEAN` with the `NOT` statement and if you want to return a `NUMBER` so that it works with SQL then compare the return value from `is_working_day` to the falsy `0` value.

Comment: Thank you so much @MT0 for your help in this. I wrote below to mitigate the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Function you have is pretty much useless in this context. You have to know whether effective_date is

- Saturday or
- Sunday or
- holiday or
- none of these

Therefore, if it returns TRUE or FALSE, you can't do anything with it. You need a new function which will return `VARCHAR2`, e.g. `sun` or `sat` or `hol` or `null` (representing a working day). Then you can use it in query you wrote. How? A simple way - without *touching* code you already have - is to use it as an inline view:

```
   OPEN p_results FOR
      SELECT conversation_id,
             CASE                                                 --> this is where you decide
                WHEN working_day_vc (effective_date) = 'sat'      --> whether day is SAT/SUN/HOLIDAY
                THEN
                   effective_date + 2
                WHEN working_day_vc (effective_date) IN ('sun', 'hol')
                THEN
                   effective_date + 1
                ELSE
                   effective_date
             END
                effective_date
        FROM (
              -- this is your current query
              SELECT DISTINCT
                     S02.CONVERSATION_ID,
                     S02.INTERNAL_USI,
                     S02.PRN,
                     S02.CRN,
                     S01.EARLIEST_B_DATE "Bank Date",
                     S01.EARLIEST_B_NARRATIVE || 'DSEC' "BN",
                     ABS (S01.TOTAL_B_AMOUNT - S02.TOTAL_C_AMOUNT) "GA",
                     DECODE (S01.EXTRA_FLAG_4,  1, 'OP',  2, 'UP')
                        "Batch Status",
                     (CASE
                         WHEN S01.latest_b_date > S02.latest_c_date
                         THEN
                            S01.latest_b_date
                         ELSE
                            S02.latest_c_date
                      END)
                        Effective_Date,
                     S02.ICC_ID,
                     S02.MATCH_METHOD,
                     S01.TOTAL_B_AMOUNT
                FROM TTPAY S01, TTCONT S02
               WHERE     S01.EXTRA_FLAG_4 IN (1, 2)
                     AND S02.EXTRA_FLAG_4 IN (1, 2)
                     AND S01.Match_no = 0
                     AND S02.Match_no = 0
                     AND S01.PRN = S02.PRN);
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is some kind of report and is executed in sql. For example

```
with
  function wf_WORKING_DAY(p_Date date) return number is
  begin
    return case when WORKING_DAY(p_Date) then 1 else 0 end;
  end;
select wf_WORKING_DAY(date'2020-01-01')
  from dual
/
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much @MT0 for your help in this.

I wrote below to mitigate the requirement.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE ACTUAL_DATE
IS
    FUNCTION IS_WORKING_DAY (IN_DATE IN DATE) RETURN BOOLEAN; 
    FUNCTION DAYS_UNTIL_NEXT_WORKING_DAY(IN_DATE IN DATE) RETURN NUMBER;
    FUNCTION GET_NEXT_BUSINESS_DAY(IN_DATE IN DATE) RETURN DATE;
END ACTUAL_DATE;
/
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY ACTUAL_DATE
IS
FUNCTION IS_WORKING_DAY (IN_DATE DATE) RETURN BOOLEAN
  IS
   HOLIDAYCOUNTER NUMBER :=0;
   DAYNUM POSITIVE;
  BEGIN
    -- CHECK DATE AGAINST NTBS_HOLIDAYS TABLE
    HOLIDAYCOUNTER :=0;
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO HOLIDAYCOUNTER
    FROM HOLIDAY_CALENDAR
    WHERE HOLIDAY_DATE = TO_DATE(IN_DATE);  
    
    -- DETERMINE IF A WEEKDAY
    DAYNUM := TO_CHAR( IN_DATE, 'd');

    -- RETURN TRUE (1) ONLY IF A WEEKDAY AND NOT A NSW PPUBLIC HOLIDAY
    IF DAYNUM BETWEEN 2 AND 6 AND HOLIDAYCOUNTER = 0 THEN 
       RETURN TRUE;
    ELSE
       RETURN FALSE;
    END IF;
END IS_WORKING_DAY;

-- DETERMINE NO. OF DAYS TO ACHIEVE NEXT WORK DAY FOR GIVEN DATE
FUNCTION DAYS_UNTIL_NEXT_WORKING_DAY(
  IN_DATE IN DATE
) RETURN NUMBER
IS
  CURRENT_DAY DATE := IN_DATE;
  NUMBERS_OF_DAY NUMBER;
BEGIN
  WHILE NOT IS_WORKING_DAY( CURRENT_DAY ) LOOP
    CURRENT_DAY := CURRENT_DAY + INTERVAL '1' DAY;
  END LOOP;
  NUMBERS_OF_DAY := CURRENT_DAY - IN_DATE;
  RETURN NUMBERS_OF_DAY;
END;

-- ADD NO.OF DAYS TO GIVEN DATE TO GET ACTUAL EFFECTIVE DATE
FUNCTION GET_NEXT_BUSINESS_DAY(IN_DATE IN DATE) RETURN DATE
    IS
        BUSINESSDAY DATE := IN_DATE;
        ACTUAL_BUSINESSDAY DATE;
    BEGIN
        IF (IN_DATE IS NULL)
        THEN
            RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR
            (
                -20999,
                'null date passed to get_next_business_day'
            );
        END IF;

        ACTUAL_BUSINESSDAY := BUSINESSDAY + DAYS_UNTIL_NEXT_WORKING_DAY(IN_DATE);
            
        RETURN ACTUAL_BUSINESSDAY;
    END;
END ACTUAL_DATE;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

By making a simplifying assumption you can reduce this process to a single query. That assumption being that you can define *a maximum number of consecutive days closed*. With that assumption when given a business date you generate a list of possible next business dates then select and return the minimum date from that list which is not contained in the holiday table. I have chosen 14 days as the maximum consecutive days closed. While the query itself is not overly complex neither is it simplistic accordingly I would hide it within a function. See [domo](http://%20https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=3725e6df5bb16d260e50bb4c17ebe377).

```
create or replace 
function next_business_day( current_business_date_in    date
                          , max_consecutive_days_closed_in integer default 14
                          )
   return date
as 
    l_next_business_day  date; 
begin 
    with day_list (possible_next_date) as 
    -- generate list of possible next business days within
    -- the defined consecutive days closed 
         (select possible_next_date 
            from (select current_business_date_in + level possible_next_date 
                    from dual 
                    connect by level < max_consecutive_days_closed_in
                 ) 
           where to_char(possible_next_date,'d') not in ('6','7')
         )
    -- next business date is the minimum date from the list 
    -- that is not in the holiday table. 
    select min(possible_next_date) 
      into l_next_business_day
      from day_list
     where possible_next_date not in 
           (select holiday_date 
              from holidays 
            union all 
            -- make sure there is a last holiday defined
            select date '9999-12-31' from dual
           );
           
    return l_next_business_day; 
end next_business_day;
```

To use, if I understand your query properly just replace your case statement with a call to the function. So

```
(CASE
     WHEN S01.latest_b_date > S02.latest_c_date
     THEN
          S01.latest_b_date
      ELSE
          S02.latest_c_date
  END) Effective_Date,
```

becomes

```
next_business_day(S01.latest_b_date) Effective_Date,
```

NOTE: Just noticed this is actually an old post, but what I initially saw was just yesterday. So I think I'll just leave it.